# Implement high-perf proxy on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy, request

I'm using NodeJS with [Luminati](https://luminati.io/) proxy, but when a 502 error occurs I need to [request another ip](https://luminati.io/faq#troubleshooting-connection_refused). Their documentation itself has a very complete example for this, but it's so complete that it confused me.

I'm not able to adapt the example to my scenario.

Here is their example that also handles 502 error:

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var promise = require('bluebird'); // promises lib used by request-promise
var lookup = promise.promisify(require('dns').lookup);
var http = require('http');
var username = 'myusername';
var password = 'mypassword';
var port = 22225;
var at_req = 0;
var n_total_req = 1000;
var n_parallel_exit_nodes = 100;
var switch_ip_every_n_req = 50;
var max_failures = 3;
var req_timeout = 60*1000;

function main(){
    http.Agent.defaultMaxSockets = Infinity;
    for (var i=0; i < n_parallel_exit_nodes; i++)
        new Session(i).start();
}

function Session(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.n_req_for_exit_node = 0;
    this.fail_count = 0;
    this.switch_session_id();
}

var proto = Session.prototype;

proto.start = proto.next = function(){
    if (at_req >= n_total_req)
        return this.cleanup(); // all done
    at_req++;
    var _this = this;
    promise.try(function(){
        if (!_this.have_good_super_proxy())
            return _this.switch_super_proxy();
    }).then(function(){
        if (_this.n_req_for_exit_node==switch_ip_every_n_req)
            _this.switch_session_id();
        var options = {
            url: 'http://lumtest.com/myip.json',
            timeout: req_timeout,
            pool: _this.pool,
            forever: true,
            proxy: _this.super_proxy_url,
        };
        return request(options);
    }).then(function success(res){
        console.log(res);
        _this.fail_count = 0;
        _this.n_req_for_exit_node++;
    }, function error(err){
        if (err.statusCode
            && !status_code_requires_exit_node_switch(err.statusCode))
        {
            // this could be 404 or other website error
            _this.n_req_for_exit_node++;
            return;
        }
        _this.switch_session_id();
        _this.fail_count++;
    }).finally(function(){
        _this.next();
    });
};

proto.have_good_super_proxy = function(){
    return this.super_proxy_host && this.fail_count < max_failures;
};

proto.update_super_proxy_url = function(){
    this.super_proxy_url = 'http://'+username+
        '-session-'+
        this.session_id+':'+password+'@'+this.super_proxy_host+':'+port;
};

proto.switch_session_id = function(){
    connection_pool_cleanup(this.pool);
    this.pool = {};
    this.session_id = (1000000 * Math.random())|0;
    this.n_req_for_exit_node = 0;
    this.update_super_proxy_url();
};

proto.switch_super_proxy = function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.switch_session_id();
    return promise.try(function(){
        return lookup('session-'+_this.session_id+
            '.'+
            'zproxy.luminati.io');
    }).then(function success(res){
        _this.super_proxy_host = res;
        _this.update_super_proxy_url();
    });
};

proto.cleanup = function(){
    connection_pool_cleanup(this.pool);
};

function connection_pool_cleanup(pool){
    if (!pool)
        return;
    for (let key in pool)
    {
        var sockets = pool[key].sockets;
        for (let name in sockets)
            sockets[name].forEach(s=>s.destroy());
    }
}

function status_code_requires_exit_node_switch(status_code){
    return [403, 429, 502, 503].indexOf(status_code)>=0;
}

main();
```

My code:

```
function add(req, res, next) {
  request({ url: 'myurl', proxy: 'myproxy' }, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    res.json(body);
  });
};

function list(req, res, next) {
  request({ url: 'myurl', proxy: 'myproxy' }, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    res.json(body);
  });
};
```

How can I adjust my code to request another ip in the same way as the example?

Answer (score 1):

The code can be written like this to retry on failure:

```
    const request = require('request-promise');
    const co = require('co');

    function add(req, res, next) {
         co(function*(){
             let last_err;
             const max_try = 10, max_fail = 3;
             for (let count=0, fail = 0; count<max_try; count++)
             {
                try {
                    let body = yield request({url: 'myurl', proxy: 'myproxy'});
                    res.json(body);
                    return;
                } catch(err){
                    last_err = err;
                    fail++;
                    if (fail==max_fail)
                    {
                        fail = 0;
                        proxy = 'myproxy2'; // switch proxy
                    }
                 }
              }
              next(last_err);
           });
    };
```